# I am trying to run a PHP app in aws server(centos), through composer but i ended up with the following error

Tags: php, laravel

This is the error it throws when I enter `'composer install'`

```
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

In Finder.php line 589:

  The "" directory does not exist.
```

I'm not sure what error this is as I don't have knowledge on PHP and I'm not sure what files I'm supposed to provide here so that my error would be understandable.

Please ask me if I need to provide any files. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

```
if (is_dir($dir)) {
                $resolvedDirs[] = $this->normalizeDir($dir);
            } elseif ($glob = glob($dir, (\defined('GLOB_BRACE') ? GLOB_BRACE : 0) | GLOB_ONLYDIR | GLOB_NOSORT)) {
                sort($glob);
                $resolvedDirs = array_merge($resolvedDirs, array_map([$this, 'normalizeDir'], $glob));
            } else {
                throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(sprintf('The "%s" directory does not exist.', $dir));
```

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you that a given directory with empty name is tried to be reached successfully. Empty directories do not really exist, so it is safe to assume that you have a dynamic value, operating probably as a setting which specifies a path in your directory structure to copy file to/from.

Your error is not unique, it happened to other people, for example here is a post on a Laravel forum: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-in-finderphp-line-547-the-directory-does-not-exist

In that discussion, the solution was to clear composer cache and update the project. That would be the first thing I would do if I were you. If that does not solve your problem, then you will need to look into Finder.php, at line 589 and see what is referred to there, then search for the definition of that path in the project and if it is not properly defined, then to define it.

EDIT

Looked into the source-code at https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Finder/Finder.php

We have this method:

```
public function in($dirs)
{
    $resolvedDirs = [];

    foreach ((array) $dirs as $dir) {
        if (is_dir($dir)) {
            $resolvedDirs[] = $this->normalizeDir($dir);
        } elseif ($glob = glob($dir, (\defined('GLOB_BRACE') ? GLOB_BRACE : 0) | GLOB_ONLYDIR | GLOB_NOSORT)) {
            sort($glob);
            $resolvedDirs = array_merge($resolvedDirs, array_map([$this, 'normalizeDir'], $glob));
        } else {
            throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(sprintf('The "%s" directory does not exist.', $dir));
        }
    }

    $this->dirs = array_merge($this->dirs, $resolvedDirs);

    return $this;
}
```

The error says:

> The "" directory does not exist.

Which means that `$dir` is empty String. This issue is caused by the fact that a wrong parameter was passed to the `in` method. If `$dirs` is an `array`, then one of its elements is empty String. If it's not an `array`, then converting it to an `array` creates an array with an empty string inside. To solve the error, the next step is to find out what `$dirs` contain and seeing the stack trace of the exception, because something wrong happened before calling this method, this method just couldn't handle the problem.

Comment: well thanks for the reply @Lajos Arpad, i researched a bit and tried to clear the cache but the error still remains, and looking in to the Finder.php i'm not able to understand where is the definition path located!

Comment: @hemanth_peddi okay, even a bad result is a result which draws us closer to the solution. Please show me line 589 of Finder.php

Comment: @ Lajos Arpad, I have updated my question and provided the lines which are in between 585-590.

Comment: @hemanth_peddi thank you, edited my answer. In short, you will need to see the stack trace and what $dirs contains.